# Merging multiple data frames in django by pandas caused a problem, which has Nan value in the result

Tags: python, django, pandas, merge, nan

the problem is that when i did merging in the views.py in django, only one raw did not work for merging, the others did merging successfully.

so i did same work in colab jupyter notebook,the result is a success, all raw showed proper results.
<veiws.py>

```
def analysis(request): 
    memo_all=Memo.objects.all()

    #convert queryset to dataframe
    df_memo=pd.DataFrame(list(memo_all.values()))
    df_list=pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\이택인\Desktop\KNOU\myproject\media\upload\sample_file.xlsx') 
    df_list=df_list.query('출금액!=0')


    data=pd.merge(df_list,df_memo,how='left',left_on='적요', right_on='memo')

    return render(request, 'report/analysis.html', {'df_memo':df_memo.to_html(), 'df_list':df_list.to_html(),'data':data.to_html()})
```

[image]

I am so hurry to complete this work. Any response from you is very helpful.
Thank you!!

Comment: maybe there is a space in the row. you first convert the number to a string, then use ```strip()``` to remove any leading or trailing spaces, then convert it back to integer. because spaces are not considered integers so maybe thats why it is giving ```NaN```. hope it will solve your issue.

Comment: I forgot to say thank you. thank you for your advice.

Comment: no problem at all Paul